# python matplotlib set xticks with hour format

Tags: python, mysql, matplotlib, plot, timestamp

In my bar chart, I need to set my `xticks` with an hour format like this:

```
6:00, 7:00, 8:00......
```

The data I used to make the chart comes from a `MySQL` database and I used `TimeStamp` in the database table. Right now the `xticks` are like this:

```
6, 7, 8......
```

I don't know how to change it in the way I want.

```
`query = """select HOUR(TimeStamp) AS Hour, SUM(Pac/12) As Pac FROM SolarData WHERE `TimeStamp` >= CURDATE() AND `TimeStamp` < CURDATE()+1 GROUP BY HOUR(TimeStamp);""";`
```

Addition: `TimeStamp` doesn't get created at the same time every day. I would prefer if the `x-axis` could be labeled as this image below:

[image]

But if I made `x-axis` like this, considering the way I made the query, there might be a potential problem: `HOUR(TimeStamp)` is an `INT` data type and the `x-axis` in the image are labeled with `STRING` data type... as long as I understand.

I tried with this query below, but I still didn't get around with the data type conflict problem. Instead of setting the `xticks`, I tried to reformat `TimeStamp` to make it like:

```
6:00,7:00,8:00,9:00...
```

instead of:

```
6,7,8,9....
```

`'%H:%00'` will make `TimeStamp` unable to work with the `plt.bar()` command at the bottom...

```
`select DATE_FORMAT(TimeStamp, '%H:%00') AS Hour, SUM(Pac/12) As Pac FROM SolarData WHERE `TimeStamp` >= CURDATE()-1 AND `TimeStamp` < CURDATE() GROUP BY HOUR(TimeStamp);`

barchart = plt.bar(TimeStamp, Pac, align='center', width=0.20, color='#FFCC33')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the method `xticks`, see for this example in matplotlib docs.

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barchart_demo2.html

Comment: Okay, my problem here is since the TimeStamp everyday doesn't start to create at the same time (it depends on the sunrise time, sometimes it's 5am, sometimes it's 7 am), this way does not seem to work with me unless this can be autoscaled or something.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the excellent [Pandas Python Data Analysis Library](http://pandas.pydata.org/index.html) to create arrays of timeseries objects based on the output of your queries. Take a look at the Pandas website that contains tons of [good examples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html). Particularly, [look here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) for how you can use pandas together with matplotlib to control the look of your x-axis.

Comment: I looked up the particular example you linked. `x_compat=True` seems fine, I need to try if this will work on my code.